# Fast vectorized way to check if a row is contained in a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have arrays of row and column coordinates

```
idx_test_r = np.array([0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4])
idx_test_c = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 6])

# in coordinates format
idx_test = np.stack((idx_test_r, idx_test_c), axis=-1)
```

and rows and column coordinates of two points

```
point_r = np.array([0, 2])
point_c = np.array([0, 2])
```

i.e. I have points with coordinates `(0, 0), (2, 2)`.

I want to determine for each row in `idx_test` if it is either equal to `(0, 0)` or to `(2, 2)`.
That is, I want a result
`[True, False, False, False, True, False]`
for the case presented here.

I know how to do it with a for loop (there are quite some examples on this site), but I need to call this function multiple times in a loop.

So **speed** is of great concern.

**Edit**

What if instead of a 1-D array `idx_test_r`, I have a 2D array, e.g.
`idx_test_r = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4], [1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5]])`
and similarly for `idx_test_c`?
I thought of

`equal_to_bad_idx = np.logical_or.reduce(np.all(bad_idx[:, None, :] == np.reshape(all_idx, (-1, 2)), axis=2))`

but this is quite slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution:

```py
x = np.stack([point_r, point_c]).T
print(np.logical_or.reduce((x[:, np.newaxis] == idx_test).all(axis=2)))
```

Prints:

```
[ True False False False  True False]
```

Comment: Do you have thoughts on my edit aswell?

Comment: @LionCereals I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. Put there what you you've tried, what is your data (size of the input, benchmark etc.)

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

idx_test_r = np.array([0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4])
idx_test_c = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 6])
idx_test = np.stack((idx_test_r, idx_test_c), axis=-1)

point_r = np.array([0, 2])
point_c = np.array([0, 2])
points = np.stack((point_r, point_c), axis=-1)

result = np.logical_or((idx_test == points[0]).all(axis=1), (idx_test == points[1]).all(axis=1))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[ True False False False  True False]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be fast enough for your use case but seems to produce the desired output:

```
point_stack = np.stack((point_r, point_c), axis=-1)

np.any(np.stack((np.all(idx_test == point_stack[0],axis=1),
                 np.all(idx_test == point_stack[1],axis=1)),
                axis=-1),axis=1)
```

Comment: Combine the `all` into one with: `np.any(np.all(idx_test[:,None,:]==pts,axis=2),axis=1)`

Comment: Yes I suspected it could be made more concise. Thanks!